Command Prompt/ Powershell loads miniconda environments. WSL loads anaconda3 environemts
When I run conda env list on Powershell, I get the following list of environments in miniconda3:
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\name\miniconda3
quant                    C:\Users\name\miniconda3\envs\quant

However, when I run it on wsl, I get the following anconda3 environemnts:
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/name/anaconda3
ai                       /home/name/anaconda3/envs/ai
dataeng                  /home/name/anaconda3/envs/dataeng
quant                 *  /home/name/anaconda3/envs/quant

How do I get my interpreter (Cursor/VScode) to access my anaconda3 environments opposed to my miniconda3 enviroments?
And does it make sense to delete miniconda3 as I am not using it?

Do you have the "WSL" extension in VS Code? You can get rid of miniconda3 on Windows itself, if you're not using it, assuming the quant environment it lists doesn't have some other purpose.

You are thinking about WSL as something on the level of "a different command prompt", but it is not. Think about it as a seperate operating system, that can access some of the same files windows can access. As such, all executable programs that you install and run under windows cannot be readibly run under WSL.
If you want conda in windows, you isntall it to windows, that is where you currently have anaconda. if you use it, then keep it
If you want conda in WSL, you need to install it there. If you don't need conda/python in WSL then delete it.
What you cannot do is have anaconda in windows (accessible from powershell) and then use it in WSL

Thats starting to make a bit more sense. Thanks! So does that mean one can't possibly install anaconda in windows and WSL? If so, why?

Hi, this may be because when WSL is installed separately, Windows and WSL are treated as two separate environments.

@abstract you can have anaconda in both windows and WSL, but for that you need to install it twice. Once for windows and once for wsl. you cannot use anaconda installed for windows in wsl and vice versa
